# What will happen if I restore my iPhone from itunes?

Tags: iphone, itunes, restore

So, What will happen if I restore my iPhone from itunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iPhone will return to factory settings as if you had a new iPhone.

Comment: And all your stuff will be synched back from the back up in iTunes. IF you had synced this particular phone before. Isn't that correct?

Comment: @Per Wikilander: Yes, if you "restore from backup" you may be able to put the info back on your iPhone that was on there last time your iPhone was synced properly.